# Why does this VBScript give me an error?

Tags: vbscript

I saved this [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) script to my local machine as c:\test.vbs:

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "This is a test"
```

When I run it from the command line, I get this error:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\test.vbs
Line:   1
Char:   1
Error:  The handle is invalid. 
Code:   80070006
Source:     (null)

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I get this under Windows Vista (SP1) and Windows XP Pro (SP3).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This link may help you:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2004-07/0979.html

It appears that the handle `StdOut` is only available when using a console host (`cscript.exe`) and not a windowed host (`wscript.exe`). If you want the code to work, you have to use `cscript.exe` to run it.

The post also describes how to change default behavior to run scripts with cscript and not wscript.

Answer (score 11):

As described by the article in the accepted answer, my script worked when I called it from the command prompt like this:

```
cscript test.vbs
```

You can also change the default script host, so that a call to cscript is not necessary every single time.  After doing that, the original command works unmodified.

```
cscript //h:cscript //s
```

You can restore the original behavior with:

```
cscript //h:wscript //s
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I submitted this solution in bug "[cscript - print output on same line on console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897698/cscript-print-output-on-same-line-on-console/13688813#13688813)" which I feel is related to this issue.

I use the following "log" function in my JavaScript to support either wscript or cscript environment. As you can see this function will write to standard output only if it can.

```
var ExampleApp = {
    // Log output to console if available.
    //      NOTE: Script file has to be executed using "cscript.exe" for this to work.
    log: function (text) {
        try {
            // Test if stdout is working.
            WScript.stdout.WriteLine(text);
            // stdout is working, reset this function to always output to stdout.
            this.log = function (text) { WScript.stdout.WriteLine(text); };
        } catch (er) {
            // stdout is not working, reset this function to do nothing.
            this.log = function () { };
        }
    },
    Main: function () {
        this.log("Hello world.");
        this.log("Life is good.");
    }
};

ExampleApp.Main();
```

Comment: according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999364/try-catch-end-try-in-vbscript   vbscript doesn't have try catch.  are you able to set a variable depending on which case it is, in vbscript?