# How to tell the difference between a VBscript is run from command line or by clicking it in a window?

Tags: scripting, command-line, vbscript

All I want to do is differentiate between the program being run by the command line or by clicking the test.vbs file in a window.

If you run the script by typing `C:\testFolder\test.vbs` in a command prompt, then I want the program to run differently than if you double clicked `test.vbs` in the `testFolder`.

Is there some system variable that I can use to differentiate between the two scenarios? I first attempted to use `WScript.Fullname` to determine if the pathname ended in cscript or wscript. But that didn't work so well.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't that work so well? That is how you determine the host executable.

Comment: The problem with checking `WScript.FullName` is that if you run a script by just typing the script name at a command prompt, it will still be run using wscript.exe (assuming that's the default script host).  You have to explicitly type `cscript test.vbs` to have it run using cscript.exe.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")

msgbox objenv("PROMPT")
```

In general PROMPT will be set to something like $P$G when run from a command prompt, but left blank when you run the .VBS file directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test against `WScript.FullName`, you can use `InStr` with `vbTextCompare` so that the match is case-insensitive.

```
If InStr(1, WScript.FullName, "cscript", vbTextCompare) Then
    WScript.Echo "Console"
ElseIf InStr(1, WScript.FullName, "wscript", vbTextCompare) Then
    WScript.Echo "Windows"
Else
    WScript.Echo "???"
End If
```

Comment: You are assuming that a) the default script host is [WScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35189167/1851270), b) in the console the script is run with CScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=(instrrev(ucase(WScript.FullName),"CSCRIPT")<>0)
```

returns -1 if running cscript, 0 if running wscript

Answer (score 0):

`WScript.FullName` contains absolute path to scripting host.

---

When script is launched using `WScript` scripting host, `WScript.FullName` contains *"wscript"* as substring, otherwise `WScript.FullName` contains *"cscript"* as substring.

---

`LCase(WScript.FullName)` is used to make **case independent** comparison.

---

```vb
bCScript = True
If InStr(1, LCase(WScript.FullName), "cscript", 1) = 0 Then
    bCScript = False
End If

' --------------------------------

If bCScript Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "CScript: " & WScript.Version
Else ' WScript
    WScript.Echo "WScript: " & WScript.Version
End If
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?