# How can a .vbs file check whether it is running through wscript.exe or cscript.exe

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for something like..

```
If RUNNING_THROUGH_WSCRIPT = True Then
    WScript.Echo "This script is running through wscript.exe"
Else
    WScript.Echo "This script is running through cscript.exe"
End If
```

I have a VBScript that can only run through `cscript.exe`. `wscript.exe` gives an error. I can easily go to properties and change default program but if say I was to give the script to a client then I would like him/her to not worry about such things.

It needs to be very easy to use without any complications beyond double-clicking on the file.

I can easily make a VBScript detect it own path and then run itself through a program of my choosing but before I can do that I need to detect the program through which it is already running.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileName( WScript.FullName )
```

The `FullName` property of the `WScript` object contains the full path of the executable host running the current script.

Comment: Already [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572833/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart, To be honest I didn't search, it was faster to answer. And probably, seeing the title in the linked question I would not have though it was relevant to this case. Is not there a better matching question? Yes, it is the same answer but (not sure if you agree) unless you know what to search in the answer (not the question) it is not obvious if it is a relevant question.

Comment: @MCND thanks I tested it works

Comment: @AsifAli just as [it did 8 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572833/692942).