# Try-Catch-End Try in VBScript doesn't seem to work

Tags: vbscript, try-catch

I'm *trying* the following code:

```
Try ' DOESN'T WORK
    Throw 2 ' How do I throw an exception?
Catch ex
    'What do I do here?
End Try
```

but I'm getting the error `Statement expected` in the catch clause.

Does anyone know how I can catch/throw exceptions in VBScript *using try/catch*? (I am *not* looking for solutions with `On Error Do X`.)

Comment: Then you're going to be *very* disappointed. There's no Try-Catch support in pre-.NET versions of VB, including VB 6, VBA, and VBScript. `On Error Resume Next` isn't so bad **if you know how to use it correctly**.

Comment: See below for some tips on using it correctly! :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

VBScript doesn't have Try/Catch. ([VBScript language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=VS.85).aspx). If it had Try, it would be listed in the Statements section.)

`On Error Resume Next` is the only error handling in VBScript. Sorry. If you want try/catch, JScript is an option. It's supported everywhere that VBScript is and has the same capabilities.

Comment: If it doesn't have Try/Catch, then how come it doesn't error on Try?

Comment: I guess it must support Trraoysfoaiuerlkj too, becuase if you change the Try to that it doesn't error there either. ;) I guess it thinks Try might be the name of the Sub that comes later in the script.

Comment: That is right, VBScript sees it as a Sub without arguments, so it doesn't error if you don't use Option Explicit or if you use On Error Resume Next. That is the reason why you should use Option Explicit regularly and On Error Resume Next sparcely. Because if you make an typo, you can easily detect it by the mention of an undeclared statement or unrecognized sub/function.

Comment: Oh, I never knew that Option Explicit works in VBScript... I only used it in VB 6, thanks! (I also thought Try was a keyword because Notepad++ highlighted Try and Catch... :\ )

Comment: @Tmdean I actually googled Trraoysfoaiuerlkj. Thanks Genius.

Comment: Under WSH, VBScript's event handling mechanism is a little simpler than in Javascript. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx).

Answer (score 81):

### Handling Errors

A sort of an "older style" of error handling is available to us in VBScript, that does make use of `On Error Resume Next`. First we enable that (often at the top of a file; but you may use it *in place of* the first `Err.Clear` below for their combined effect), then before running our possibly-error-generating code, clear any errors that have already occurred, run the possibly-error-generating code, and then explicitly check for errors:

```
On Error Resume Next
' ...
' Other Code Here (that may have raised an Error)
' ...
Err.Clear      ' Clear any possible Error that previous code raised
Set myObj = CreateObject("SomeKindOfClassThatDoesNotExist")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Number
    WScript.Echo "Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)
    WScript.Echo "Source: " &  Err.Source
    WScript.Echo "Description: " &  Err.Description
    Err.Clear             ' Clear the Error
End If
On Error Goto 0           ' Don't resume on Error
WScript.Echo "This text will always print."
```

Above, we're just printing out the error if it occurred. If the error was fatal to the script, you could replace the second `Err.clear` with  `WScript.Quit(Err.Number)`.

Also note the `On Error Goto 0` which turns off resuming execution at the next statement when an error occurs.

If you want to test behavior for when the `Set` succeeds, go ahead and comment that line out, or create an object that will succeed, such as `vbscript.regexp`.

The `On Error` directive only affects the current running scope (current `Sub` or `Function`) and does not affect calling or called scopes.

---

### Raising Errors

If you want to check some sort of state and then raise an error to be handled by code that calls your function, you would use `Err.Raise`. `Err.Raise` takes up to five arguments, `Number`, `Source`, `Description`, `HelpFile`, and `HelpContext`. Using help files and contexts is beyond the scope of this text. `Number` is an error number you choose, `Source` is the name of your application/class/object/property that is raising the error, and `Description` is a short description of the error that occurred.

```
If MyValue <> 42 Then
    Err.Raise(42, "HitchhikerMatrix", "There is no spoon!")
End If
```

You could then handle the raised error as discussed above.

---

<sub>**Change Log**</sub>

<sub>Edit #1: 
Added an `Err.Clear` before the possibly error causing line to clear any previous errors that may have been ignored.</sub>

<sub>Edit #2:
Clarified.</sub>

<sub>Edit #3:
Added comments in code block. Clarified that there was expected to be more code between `On Error Resume Next` and `Err.Clear`. Fixed some grammar to be less awkward. Added info on `Err.Raise`. Formatting.</sub>

Comment: I prefer "If Err" instead of "If Err.Number <> 0", but that's mostly a style preference.

Comment: I was gonna change it, but it feels a little weird to me to be calling Err.Clear and using a "if not null" style check after. All down to style preference.

Comment: The first `Err.Clear` is superfluous as `On Error Resume Next` resets the `Err` object for you. Also make no mention of `Err.Raise` a very useful tool in the VBScript Error Handling arsenal.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks. I have clarified why I had the first `Err.Clear`. I have added information about `Err.Raise`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarity. On the topic of Raising errors you might find [this article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/021201-1.shtml) interesting

Answer (score 4):

Try Catch **exists** via workaround in VBScript:

http://web.archive.org/web/20140221063207/http://my.opera.com/Lee_Harvey/blog/2007/04/21/try-catch-finally-in-vbscript-sure

```
Class CFunc1
    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        WScript.Echo "Starting"
        Dim i : i = 65535 ^ 65535 
        MsgBox "Should not see this"
    End Sub

    Private Sub CatchErr
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 6 WScript.Echo "Overflow handled!" 
            Case Else WScript.Echo "Unhandled error " & Err.Number & " occurred."
        End Select
        Err.Clear
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        CatchErr
        WScript.Echo "Exiting" 
    End Sub 
End Class

Dim Func1 : Set Func1 = New CFunc1 : Set Func1 = Nothing
```

Comment: While this is kinda cool, in the sense that it's clever, "clever" code is rarely readable or easily maintainable/usable. I'm not comfortable doing a -1 on this, but this really is "bad code" for production purposes. Cool academically though.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, especially when you work with VB, you can miss obvious solutions. Like I was doing last 2 days.

the code, which generates error needs to be moved to a separate function. And in the beginning of the function you write `On Error Resume Next`. This is how an error can be "swallowed", without swallowing any other errors. Dividing code into small separate functions also improves readability, refactoring & makes it easier to add some new functionality.

Comment: Or you could put `On Error Goto 0` after the code that generates your error, so that you don't incur the overhead of a function call (and don't need tiny functions that don't do any real work).