# Using Custom Error Message in Classic ASP when Database connection is down

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, error-handling, database-connection

We have a site that is running IIS 6 and ASP classic. We connect to an Oracle database to gather information to display on this web-page. When the database is down the end-users see a typical asp error message about being unable to connect to the database. I would like to display a custom error message that would read something like "The database is currently unavailable at this time".  Can anyone provide the syntax in ASP using an oracle connection string to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use;

```
On Error Resume Next

Set con = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
con.Open "Provider=myOracleProvider;Data Source=myOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

If Err.Number = 0 And con.Errors.Count = 0 Then
    'No problems connecting to DB so don't do anything
ELSE
    'Problems connecting to DB so do something to handle this or alert adm
END IF

On Error goto 0
```

Obviously adapt the connection string to suit your specific Oracle environment and database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a try catch like syntax in classic asp. use an on error resume next. Please read more aout this at [Try-Catch-End Try in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999364/try-catch-end-try-in-vbscript). Then you can reset the error status to 0 just before the db connection initialization. You can even have a function to collect all the error messages and dispaly at the end.

```
dim error_string 'initiate the variable

            function readAndSetErrors(msg) 'Custom error message function

                if err <> 0 then
                    error_string = error_string & "<br/>" msg 'Add the custom error message if there is an error           

                end if
                  set err = 0 'rest the error 
            end function

            On Error Resume Next
        'Connection string 
        strConnection = "driver={oracle in instantclient_11_2};DataSource=XYZ;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
        Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") ' create connection object

        set err = 0 'Reset the err just in case
        objConn.Open (strConnection )  ' open the connection
        function readAndSetErrors("The database is currently unavailable at this time") 'execute the function
    ' more code and may be more function calls

    Response.write(error_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, Everyone. On andy's suggestions I get my custom error messgae, but also it displays the database or vbscript error messgae and code as well. Any way to get rid of this.

Comment: Sorry. I hit the enter key ny mistake. Jeevaka, I tried your suggestion, but for whatever reason my error message does not display on the screen. It gets to the error (I chnaged the database password to create an artifical error) and displays the page (the on error resume works!) but the response.write messgae does not appear.   Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I found the solution.